# Function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I'm trying to create a simple function to return user location based on browser but it keeps returning undefined:

```
  function getLocation() {
    //get current location
    var geo_param;
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        // Create geolocation parameter
        geo_param = "geolocation=[" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "]";
        console.log(geo_param)
      });
    }
    return geo_param
  }

  function search(activity) {
    var searchUrl = "/s?activity=" + activity + "&" + getLocation()
    window.location.href = searchUrl;
    console.info(searchUrl)
  }
```

Comment: if `getCurrentPostion` is asynchronous, you'll get undefined return.

Comment: if `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, then the function will return geo_param **BEFORE** the callback in getCurrentPosition is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your function executes before the response is being fetched. You need to have a callback function once you get the response from the `API`.

Also note you did not have `query string key` **geo_param** in redirection URL

Try this:

```
function getLocation(cb) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geo_param = "geolocation=[" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "]";
            if (typeof cb === 'function') {
                cb(geo_param);
            }
        });
    }
}
function search(activity) {
    getLocation(function (geo_param) {
        window.location.href = "/s?activity=" + activity + "&" + geo_param;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. I do have the query string key however, it's called geolocation. So it looks like '&geolocation=[lon,lat]` the way you have  it would return `&geo_param=geolocation=[lon,lat]`

Comment: @Batman, Ooh yes! I got that wrong..

Comment: But yea it works perfectly. Thanks a lot, I think I'm getting it now. So in order to save the result of the async function, I need to pass it to another function and work with it from there.

Comment: Yeah exactly! For `async` operations as functions are first-class objects, we can pass a function as an argument in another function and later execute that passed-in function or even return it to be executed later.

Comment: Ah okay, I get it, a little confusing but I understand. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The getCurrentPosition scope is asynchronous, so `geo_param` will be returned before getCurrentPosition finished runnning. An solution to this is using a callback, see my example below.

```js
 function getLocation(callback, activity) {
     //get current location
     var geo_param;
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
             // Create geolocation parameter
             geo_param = "geolocation=[" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "]";
             console.log(geo_param);
             callback(geo_param, activity);
         });
     }
 }

 function search(activity) {
     getLocation(search_with_current_location, activity);
 }

 function search_with_current_location(geo_param, activity) {
     var searchUrl = "/s?activity=" + activity + "&" + geo_param;
     window.location.href = searchUrl;
     console.info(searchUrl);
 }
```